# Partial Rendered in index.html.erb Won't Display in show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial

A beginner here, so, please bear with me.  :)

I have a partial in a partial that's displaying correctly in my `views > products > index.html.erb`:

```
<div>
 <table>
  ...
   <tbody>
    <%= render product %>
   </tbody>
  ...
 </table>
</div>
```

This is the `_product` partial:

```
<div>
 <td>
  <%= render "product_row", product: product, order_item: @order_item %>
 </td>
</div>
```

..which points to this `_product_row` partial:

```
<div>
  <%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= number_to_currency product.price %>
   <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1 %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
   <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

All is well, BUT I want to display `_product_row` in my `views > products > show.html.erb` instead.  So, I copy and paste it and get this error:

```
NameError in Products#show
undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:...>
Extracted source:
<%= render "product_row", product: product, order_item: @order_item %>
```

...so I go in my `products_controller` and put this:

```
def show
 @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @product }
  end
end
```

'still the same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering your partial from `index.html.erb` file like:

```
<%= render product %>
```

here, `product` variable is not defined as a local variable in the view file. From your controller's index action pass product variable as a instance variable like `@product` or define it in the `index.html` page.

Or, you can do simply like that:
in **products_controller > index**

```
def index 
  @products = Product.all
end
```

in **products > index.html.erb**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div>
 <table>
  ...
   <tbody>
    <%= render product %>
   </tbody>
  ...
 </table>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Running with this, I went in my `products_controller` and put this:
    `def index
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end`
and still get the same error.  :(

Comment: If you are going with the traditional rails routing, then the `products_controller > index` does not accept any **id** parameter. So, if you want to do so then you need to customize the index method route.

Comment: Okay. Modify `methods > product.rb` with a rule for `index`.  'will try that later.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: for your existing code, pass  `product` like `<%= render Product.last %>` in **index.html.erb** file to see if it works.

Comment: Oh, and I already have this in my `products_controller`
    `def index
    @products = Product.all
    end`
:)

Comment: See, it's working fine in my `index`.  What I'm trying to do is have the same thing display in my `show`.

Comment: Ok, for your `show.html.erb` it would be `<%= render @product %>`

Comment: `<%= render @product %>` in my `show.html.erb` worked!  Thanks!  You guys are awesome!

Comment: @slave_unit, Then you should close the question by accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you probably have some loop as follows in your `index.html.erb`

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render product %>
<% end %>
```

Here `product` in the `render` call refers to the local variable you defined in the block of the iterator.

But when you try to copy/paste the same code to your `show.html.erb`, `product` will is considered undefined as it is out of the loop.

So you should use the following:

```
<%= render @product %>
```

in your `show.html.erb`, assuming you must have assigned `@product` in your `show` action.

Comment: Dude, that's exactly how my `index.html.erb` looks like!  And `<%= render @product %>` worked in my `show.html.erb`!  Thanks!  You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

@Emu and @Dharam suggested that I put

`<%= render @product %>` instead of `<%= render product %>`

in my Product `show.html.erb` and making sure `@product` is defined in my `products_controller.rb`, which I did:

`def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end`

It worked!  No more `undefined` errors.

I did have some styling issues with this, though.  Long story-short, I copied and pasted what was in my `_product_row` partial (see original code in the question above) into my Product `show` instead of rendering it.  Then I modified it a bit basing on Emu and Dharam's suggestion.  Basically it planted the idea to try to add `@`s where it errors out as undefined:

```
<div>
 <%= form_for @order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
  <h4 style="font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', sans-serif;">The Small Price to Pay: 
   <span style="color: green">
    <%= number_to_currency @product.price %>
   </span>
  </h4>
  <h4 style="font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', sans-serif;">How many:</h4>
  <div class="input-group">
   <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1 %>
   <div class="input-group-btn, add-to-cart-button">
    <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id %>
    <%= f.submit "ADD IT", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Then added this to my `products_controller.rb`:

`def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @order_item = current_order.order_items.new
end`

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks, again, all.  :)